# Remysharp's js Inview plugin fired velocity transition twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I'm using the [**Remysharp In View**](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin) plugin to determine when an element is in view. When it is in view, I use velocity to show that element in. For some reason, inside of the In view call, the animation triggers twice. Outside of the In View call, it works as it should.

Why is it firing twice?

```
$(".xslideUpIn").one('inview', function (event, visible) {
      if (visible == true) {
         $(".xslideUpIn").velocity('transition.slideUpIn', { stagger: 700 }).delay(1000)
      } else {
        // element has gone out of viewport
      }
});
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle for this ? I suspect it is firing twice because velocity may synchronously move the viewport, firing another event while your function has not yet been unbound. try using setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$(".xslideUpIn").one('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $(".xslideUpIn").velocity('transition.slideUpIn', { stagger: 700 }).delay(1000)
     }, 0);
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});
```

Comment: Just tried this, still triggers the animation twice.

Comment: A jsfiddle could help